# Sum a list of lists of integers per index in erlang

Tags: erlang

erlang newbie here. I have a list of lists like

```
[[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[5,2,9]]
```

I would like to sum each index in the lists so the result would be

```
[6,3,11]
```

This is what I have so far where Values is my list of lists:

```
fun(Keys, Values, ReReduce) ->
    lists:foldl(fun(V, A) ->
        lists:zipwith(fun(X, Y) -> X+Y end, V, A)
        end, [0, 0, 0], Values)
end.
```

Is there a faster/better way of achieving this?

Some other points -
"Values" is a list of lists. Each list in the list will have 3 integers always. There is an unknown of lists in the lists.

Eg: `[[0,1,1],[2,4,6],[3,3,7],[1,0,1]`

I am not using the Keys or ReReduce parameters, they are just expected to be there by CouchDB. I cannot define/declare anything outside of my function, its not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look for the most efficient (12-25ms for 1M (1000x1000) in OTP20 on Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz depending if you hit GC or not so about 30 CPU cycles per value, not bad for interpreted language huh) solution:

```
sum(L) ->
    case sum(L, [], 0) of
        {_, []} -> [];
        {S, Ts} -> [S | sum(Ts)]
    end.

sum([], Ts, Acc) -> {Acc, Ts};
sum([[H|T] | L], Ts, Acc) ->
    sum(L, [T|Ts], H+Acc);
sum([_|L], Ts, Acc) ->
    sum(L, Ts, Acc).
```

There is more elegant solution:

```
sum2([]) -> [];
sum2(L) ->
    S = lists:sum([H || [H|_] <- L]),
    case [T || [_|T] <- L] of
        [] -> [];
        Ts -> [S | sum2(Ts)]
    end.
```

There is even more elegant but less forgiving solution (when above are pretty happy with inputs like `[[], [1,2], [3]]` this one will raise the error exception)

```
sum3([]) -> [];
sum3([[]|_]) -> [];
sum3(L) ->
    S = lists:sum([hd(X) || X <- L]),
    Ts = [tl(X) || X <- L],
    [S | sum3(Ts)].
```

fun version of `sum/1` solution

```
fun(Keys, Values, ReReduce) ->
    SumAndTail = fun
        F([], Ts, Acc) -> {Acc, Ts};
        F([[H|T] | L], Ts, Acc) ->
            F(L, [T|Ts], H+Acc);
        F([_|L], Ts, Acc) ->
            F(L, Ts, Acc)
    end,
    Sum = fun G(L) ->
        case SumAndTail(L, [], 0) of
            {_, []} -> [];
            {S, Ts} -> [S | G(Ts)]
        end
    end,
    Sum(Values)
end.
```

Given the limitation and properties (`Values` will never be empty for example) of CouchDB reduce function I would consider your solution with a little tweak as the most elegant

```
fun(Keys, Values, ReReduce) ->
    lists:foldl(fun(V, A) ->
        lists:zipwith(fun(X, Y) -> X+Y end, V, A)
        end, hd(Values), tl(Values))
end.
```

**Edit**:

Actually, there is not the one most efficient solution. `sum/1` above would be the most efficient for lists with long sublists like 1000 sublists with 1000 values as measured above. For much shorter sublists, the original approach seems much more appropriate. The difference is how much GC you perform due to intermediate data structures. If you have short sublists this solution will be much more efficient

```
sum5([]) -> [];
sum5([H|T]) ->
    sum5(H, T).

sum5(Acc, []) -> Acc;
sum5(Acc, [H|T]) ->
    sum5(sum5zip(Acc, H), T).

sum5zip([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) ->
    [H1+H2|sum5zip(T1, T2)];
sum5zip([], L2) -> L2;
sum5zip(L1, []) -> L1.
```

Comment: I can only write code inside the couchdb function. Like bxdoans answer I don't know how to apply this inside `fun(Keys, Values, ReReduce)`. I get syntax errors.

Comment: @Sam Ok, I will give you fun solution. (Pun intended :-)

Comment: @Sam Given CouchDB limitation your solution with a little tweak is probably the most elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks Hynek. This does me the added benefit of seeing how to adapt those examples to the _fun_ style :) So I almost had it, just need some head/tail magic :D

Comment: @Sam I think `fold` + `zipwith` is actually even faster than "fun" solution. It seems that funs pays heavy price compared to functions.

Answer (score 2):

Hope that help :)

```
d()->
    [A,B,C] = [[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[5,2,9]],
    F = fun(X,Y,Z) -> X+Y+Z end,
    lists:zipwith3(F,A,B,C).
```

I change a little bit my code, I think it adapt you

```
d(L) when hd(L) == [] -> [];
d(L)-> [lists:sum([hd(A) || A <- L ])] ++ d([tl(B) || B <- L]).
```

Result in shell:

```
1> test:d([[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[5,2,9]]).
[6,3,11]
```

So your `func` will like below:

```
fun(Keys, Values, ReReduce) ->
    d(Values)
end.
```

Comment: This approach requires me to "know" i have 3 lists in my list? I've modified my code with a bit more context. Its a couchdb reduce function.

Comment: Thanks bxdoan but I couldn't work out how to use that in my function.

Comment: Can you provide full function you want with all real value input Keys, Values (list of list), ReReduce and output you expect?

Comment: I added some more info. The function shown is whole example. I cannot change the function signature or declare anything outside of it. Everything must happen within that function.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems to work, even if you have unused parameters (Keys and ReReduce), but you still have to know the size of the inner list, it is implicit in the initial accumulator: `[0,0,0]`

You can avoid this with a very small modification:

```
1>F = F = fun(Lists = [_L|_]) when is_list(_L) ->
1>    lists:foldl(
1>        fun(List,AccList) -> lists:zipwith(fun(X,Y) -> X+Y end,List,AccList) end,
1>        hd(Lists),
1>        tl(Lists))
1>    end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.99386804>
2> F([[1],[2]]).                                                                    
[3]
3> F([[]]).                                                                         
[]
4> F([[0,1,1,2],[1,0,1,5],[5,2,9,4],[8,2,7,1]]).                                                 
[14,5,18,12]
5> F([1,2]).                                                                        
** exception error: no function clause matching erl_eval:'-inside-an-interpreted-fun-'([1,2])
```

The second function provided by @bxdoam works the same, it is not obvious (to me) to say which one has the best performances.

I think that bxdoam solution can be improved by replacing the line

```
d(L)-> [lists:sum([hd(A) || A <- L ])] ++ d([tl(B) || B <- L]).
```

with

```
d(L)-> [lists:sum([d([tl(B) || B <- L]|[hd(A) || A <- L ])]]).
```

**[edit]**

If the inner list has a fixed size of 3, the simplest and fastest solution will be:

```
fun(Keys, Values, ReReduce) ->
    lists:foldl(fun([X,Y,Z],[Sx,Sy,Sz]) -> [X+Sx,Y+Sy,Z+Sz] end, [0,0,0],Values)
end.
```

Comment: The size of the inner list is constant (3). The number of lists in the top list is variable.  I dont know what to do with bxdoam's solution. I just get syntax errors.